# Referring to Undetermined Placeholder Size In Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

There is a case where I need to make an elementwise comparison between output of my model and a constant. However, the output of the model has a size depending on a placeholder, and it seems difficult to refer to constants of that same size.

This first attempt somehow produces a scalar value rather than doing elementwise operations:

```
tf.less(y,tf.constant(k,dtype=tf.float32))
```

This second attempt has elementwise behavoir, but is a kludge:

```
 tf.less(y,tf.constant(k,shape= [<INT_GREATER_THAN_BATCHSIZE>],dtype=tf.float32))
```

Is there a clean way to refer to the yet-undetermined size of the placeholder in the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to refer to the shape of a (dynamically sized) tensor is using the [`tf.shape(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) op, which produces at runtime a vector of integers that contain the true shape of a tensor `x`.

Note that `tf.constant()` does not accept a dynamic shape as an argument—for then it would not be constant!—but the similar [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#fill) op does.

Therefore you can write:

```
p = tf.placeholder(..., shape=[None])
# ...
result = tf.less(y, tf.fill(tf.shape(p), tf.constant(k, dtype=tf.float32)))
```

---

PS. Note that, if `k` is a scalar, the [`tf.less()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#less) op *should* broadcast the shape of `k` to match `y`, and the following should work:

```
tf.less(y, tf.constant(k, dtype=tf.float32))
```

...but it's not clear why that's not working for you.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Unfortunately I don't have time at the moment to investigate why it didn't broadcast.